# Enrollment and verification of fingerprint by different company device

Tags: java, fingerprint, ansi, digital-persona-sdk

I have successfully integrated two different company fingerprint sdk with my applications . Suppose they are company x and Y .

I can enroll fingerprint by company x sdk and verify fingerprint from their sdk by their device . Similarly I can enroll fingerprint by company y sdk and verify fingerprint from their device by their sdk .

What I want to do now is that I will enroll fingerprint data by company x sdk and will verify it from company y sdk . How can I do that ? Both company sdk uses ANSI standard data .

## My queries:

I have come to know that this is possible by converting the raw byte data to wsq format . But when I want to convert ANSI standard finger dat to wsq format , my application crashes .

So I want to know the following queries :

(1) Is ANSI data convertible to wsq format ? I have used the following function to convert ANSI data to wsq format .

```
public long WSQGetEncodedImageSize (int[] wsqImageOutSize, float wsqBitRate, byte[] fingerImage, int width, int height, int pixelDepth, int ppi)


public long WSQEncode (byte[] wsqImageOut, float wsqBitRate, byte[] fingerImage, int width, int height, int pixelDepth, int ppi)
```

(2) What can I do to enroll finger data from one company sdk and verify that data from another company sdk ?

(3) What is the relation of ANSI standard data and wsq standard data ?

Comment: _"when I want to convert ANSI standard finger dat to wsq format , my application crashes "_ -- you need to provide complete details on the crash, including the data you were trying to process, as well as the source code that does the vonbersion.  Withot that at a minimum the question is off-topic.

Comment: What is the standard procedure to enroll fingerdata by one finger and verify that data with other company sdk ?